# Rollback SqlServer em gravação de duas tabelas distintas

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

**Premissa:**

Estou usando EntityFramework6 para persistência de dados no SQLServer.
Num certo período preciso gravar dados em duas tabelas diferentes, 
porém a segunda tabela possui dependência da primeira exemplo.

```
try{

    MetodoPersisteNaTabelaA();

    MetodoPersisteNaTabelaB();

}
exception(Exception e){
    Erro();
}
```

Preciso que se houver erro na gravação da tabela B que dê rollback na tabela A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bom dia, no caso você deve estar instanciando a conexão em algum momento, seja dentro do método ou na construção da classe, nessa conexão, sugiro que utilize do recurso de transação do próprio EF e após a utilização dos métodos execute o comit do objeto de contexto ou o rollback no caso de erro.

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
    using (var dbContextTransaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction()) 
    { 
        try 
        { 
            MetodoPersisteNaTabelaA();
            MetodoPersisteNaTabelaB();
            context.SaveChanges();
            dbContextTransaction.Commit(); 
        }
        catch (Exception) 
        { 
            dbContextTransaction.Rollback(); 
        } 
    }
}
```

Segue link do msdn com mais explicações do assunto: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn456843(v=vs.113).aspx